# Splitting code up into functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, function

Due to performance and other issues, I want to split my code into seperate functions as before it was just one big ".ready" function.

I am new to javaScript/jquery but I thought I would give it a go myself. I have done exactly the way I thought it was done but my console is telling me things are undefined so I am guessing I have got things out of scope. I have read up on it in more detail, but still have not got anywhere.

My code works OK at the moment but I want to get into the habbit of clean coding. Can someone point out where I am going wrong so I can carry on myself?

Here is an example of what I have so far

```
//Global variables
var randomWord = [];
var listOfWords = [];
var populationNumber = [];
var attemptNumber = [];
var completionNumber = [];
var gridSize = [];

generateGrid();

startMusic();

randomizeReward();


//Click event to start the game
$(".start-btn-wrapper").click(function () {
    startplay();
});
//Click event to restart the game
$(".restart-btn").click(function () {
    restartplay();
});
```

Thanks

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QYaGP/

Fiddle with HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/QYaGP/1/

Comment: Not a full, workign example in jsfiddle without the HTML, but my immediate guess would be this: you're "global scope" variables are only global to the ready state.  The functions outside of the ready don't have access to those variables.  Move them above the jquery `ready` function so they're truly global and those other functions can access them.

Comment: Ok great I will try that Eli Gassert

Comment: Learn about JavaScript variable scope and read about [functional programming](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter6.html)

Comment: No difference I'm affraid @EliGassert

Comment: Add HTML to the jsfiddle to make it a functional example so we can truly see what's going on.  Too much JS to just parse visually and determine the issue.

Comment: Why do you ask questions under two different accounts?

Comment: read about javascript classes and jquery plugins
http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/   

. Use them for split and group your functions

Comment: He is my collegue, I am trying to help him out @user1689607

Answer (score 0):

You need to start passing some information into the functions you're defining. If your functions all have no arguments, then you will have to use globally defined variables, hardcoded references to jquery selections etc in order to get anything done.

So as an example, you have a function

```
function replaySound() {
    $("#hintSound").attr('src', listOfWords[randomWord].hintSound);
    hintSound.play();
}
```

This is actually going to play the sound detailed in `listOfWords[randomWord]` via the element `#hintSound`. You could do that via:

```
function playSound(selector, wordlistEntry) {
    $(selector).attr('src', wordlistEntry.hintSound);
    $(selector)[0].play();
}
```

And then instead of calling `replaySound()`, you'd call:

```
playSound('#hintSound', listOfWords[randomWord]);
```

This way the *behaviour* that you want is wrapped up in the function, but the *specifics*, i.e. the data you need for it, are passed in via the arguments. That allows you to reuse the function to play any sound using any selector, not just `#hintSound`.

You'll find as you do that that you need to start choosing what a function will act on in the code that calls it, rather than in the function. That's good, because the context of what you're trying to achieve is there in the calling code, not in the function. This is known as 'separation of concerns'; you try to keep logic about a given thing confined to one area, rather than spreading it about in lots of functions. But you still want functions to allow you to encapsulate behaviour. This allows you to change behaviour cleanly and easily, without having to rewrite everything every time some part of the logic changes.

The result should be that you find several functions actually did the same thing, but with different specifics, so you can just have one function instead and reuse it. That is the Don't Repeat Yourself principle, which is also important.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about performance, I would look into using an framework such as AngularJS.  You can inject modularized code.  Even better, with MVC your view is bound to your model so by changing the model the view automatically updates itself.

Also, stop using class selectors.  Use ID selectors.  They are much faster.  You also want to preload selectors (even with class selectors).  That way you are only searching the DOM once:

```
var ele = $('#elementId');

$(ele).doSomething();
```

This way, you have a reference to the DOM element.  You can use a datastructure to store all of your references outside of the global scope:

```
var elementReferences = {}; //declaration
elementReferences.mainPage = {}; //use
elementReferences.mainPage.root = $('#mainPage'); //load the root div of a page segment
elementReferences.mainPage.title =   $(elementReferences.mainPage.root).children('#title'); //load the title 

elementReference.mainPage.form = $(elementReferences.mainPage.root).children('#form'); //load the form
```

Now you can do this:

```
$(elementReference.mainPage.form).whatever();
```

and it doesn't have to search the DOM for the element.  This is especially useful for larger apps.

If you put a function within document.ready, as per your fiddle, you are only able to access that function within the scope of the document.ready call.  You really want to be able to load/unload functions as needed dynamically within the scope that they are required in, which is where angularjs comes into play.

You also, for the most part, want to remove your functions and variables from the global scope and put them into containers that are sorted by their dependencies and use.  This is Object Oriented Programming 101.  Instead of having a bunch of arrays sitting within the global scope where they could be overwritten by mistake by another developer, you want to put them within a container:

```
var arrays = {}; //create the object

arrays.whatever1 = [];
arrays.whatever2 = [];
```

Obviously, you will probably want a more descriptive name than "arrays".  Functions work the same manner:

```
var ajax = {}; //ajax object
var ajax.get = function(){
};
var ajax.post = function(){
};
var ajax.delete = function(){
};
```

This generally promotes cleaner code that is more reusable and easier to maintain.  You want to spend a good portion of your time writing a spec that fully documents the overall architecture before actually beginning development.  NEVER jump the gun if you can help it.  Spend time thoroughly researching and planning out the big picture and how everything fits together rather than trying to wing it and figure it out as you go.  You spend less time having to reinvent the wheel when you do it this way.

It's developed by google, so it should be around for quite a while.  I'm not sure if you are the guy in charge of your system's architecture, but if performance/reusability is an issue at your company it is definitely worth taking a look at.  I'd be more than happy to give you a walkthrough regarding most of what I know in terms of software architecture and engineering.  Just MSG me if you are interested.  Always happy to help!